# Is my installation of python-pip broken?

Tags: python, pip, ubuntu-14.04, file-permissions

I used the following commands to install and upgrade pip,

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev build-essential
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
```

After this I just tried Installing virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper but I got these warnings

```
achyut@achyut-Inspiron-3537:~$ sudo pip install --upgrade virtualenv
The directory '/home/achyut/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/achyut/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting virtualenv
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Downloading virtualenv-13.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.7MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.7MB 206kB/s 
Installing collected packages: virtualenv
Successfully installed virtualenv-13.1.2
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
```

I've had this problem before, and I think it was also the reason I was unable to get buildozer to work, broke my kivy-dev setup. In the end I thought it was something I did before and had to nuke my ubuntu system. I want to know and fix this problem understand its cause. I tried to fix the permissions problem with this(after trying to do it with the properties using GUI):

```
achyut@achyut-Inspiron-3537:~$ sudo chown -R achyut:achyut /path
```

but was not successful and both problems still persist.

Comment: I would not worry about it, it is not going to cause any problems using pip. Your `InsecurePlatformWarning`  can be fixed with `pip install requests[security]`

Comment: I thought so but my dev environ not working made me paranoid so I just posted it thinking that it might get me some leads, anyway I will update or remove this if my dev-environ starts to work right.

Comment: How did you kivy-dev env break?

Comment: I tried your suggestion, here[link] (http://pastebin.com/PhEqj2Yu) is the log. I had multiple versions of python and cython installed, didn't use virtalenv and messed everything up. In the end pip was very much broken.

Comment: pip is not broken at all, where in the output does it show that it is?

Comment: " I had multiple versions of python and cython installed, didn't use virtalenv and messed everything up. In the end pip was very much broken." Was the answer to "How did you kivy-dev env break?"

Comment: Ah ok, I thought you meant pip was broken based on your output, is  the insecure warning gone now?

Comment: Yes, thanks for that.